# How to create a dynamic grid containing panels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a requirement to dynamically create a WPF Grid that has 3 columns and the number of rows will depend on the amount of panels I need. The first panel will be in grid location 0,0 the next in 0,1 -> 0,2 -> 1,0 -> 1,1 etc.. So if I needed 20 panels the grid would have 3 cols and 7 rows. And the Grid should fill the whole window

And each panel should have a heading and a progress bar on it. I guess I would have my panel as a seperate user control

I'm starting out with WPF so any help would be great

Thanks a lot

Comment: what code do I have to write to acheive the above?

Comment: what code did you try up to now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows how you can create the number of rows and columns and put objects (in this case a Label) into each cell.  See if you can extrapolate from there.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Grid grid1;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int cellCount = 14;
        int numCols = 3;
        int numRows = (cellCount + 1) / numCols;
        grid1 = new Grid();

        this.AddChild(grid1);

        for(int i=0; i<numCols; ++i)
            this.grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i)
            this.grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

        foreach (var g in this.grid1.RowDefinitions)
        {
            g.Height = new GridLength(100);
        }

        foreach (var g in grid1.ColumnDefinitions)
        {
            g.Width = new GridLength(100);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<cellCount; ++i)
        {
            int idx = grid1.Children.Add(new Label());
            Label x = grid1.Children[idx] as Label;

            x.Content = "Cell " + i;
            x.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i/numCols);
            x.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i % numCols);
        }
    }
}
```

This examples starts with a nearly completely empty XAML.  All it has is the Window element.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do it in code-behind as far as I know.

You'll just divide the needed cells by 3 and round up.

Derive a control from grid.
Create a custom attached property for cell number.
Then override MeasureOverride, and set the grid rowdefinitions by the rounded-up row count. Then set grid.row and grid.column on each item to correspond to the cell number you read from the controls.

Then call the default grid.measureoverride.

```
public class ArrangeGrid : Grid
{
    public ArrangeGrid()
    {
        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    }
    public static DependencyProperty GridCellProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GridCell", typeof(int), typeof(ArrangeGrid));

    public static void SetGridCell(UIElement element, int value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ArrangeGrid.GridCellProperty, value);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForChildren]
    public static int GetGridCell(UIElement element)
    {
        return (int)element.GetValue(ArrangeGrid.GridCellProperty);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        RowDefinitions.Clear();

        int rowCount = this.Children.Count / 3;
        if (this.Children.Count % 3 != 0)
        {
            rowCount += 1;
        }

        while (RowDefinitions.Count < rowCount)
        {
            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        }

        foreach (var child in this.Children)
        {

            int gridCell = ArrangeGrid.GetGridCell((UIElement)child);
            int gridRow = gridCell / 3;
            int gridCol = gridCell % 3;

            ((UIElement)child).SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, gridRow);
            ((UIElement)child).SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, gridCol);

        }

        return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    }
}
```

Obviously you could do this without the GridCell property. And there's a few bugs in there if you skip grid cells, but you should be able to adapt this code to your use.