# Creating a dynamic grid with panels

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm very new to C# and just playing around with things at the moment. I was trying to create a grid in a window with buttons or labels in it. I stumbled upon this question [How to create a dynamic grid containing panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654906/how-to-create-a-dynamic-grid-containing-panels/11656598#11656598)

I've tried to implement this received an error stating

> "Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   PresentationFramework.dll" at the this.addchild line. I've attached
>   what I have below.

*note this isn't homework, I'm just playing around to familiarize myself with c#

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Grid grid1;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int cellCount = 14;
            int numCols = 3;
            int numRows = (cellCount + 1) / numCols;
            grid1 = new Grid();

            this.AddChild(grid1);


            for (int i = 0; i < numCols; ++i)
                this.grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i)
                this.grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

            foreach (var g in this.grid1.RowDefinitions)
            {
                g.Height = new GridLength(100);
            }

            foreach (var g in grid1.ColumnDefinitions)
            {
                g.Width = new GridLength(100);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < cellCount; ++i)
            {
                int idx = grid1.Children.Add(new Label());
                Label x = grid1.Children[idx] as Label;

                x.Content = "Cell " + i;
                x.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i / numCols);
                x.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i % numCols);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the xaml? I suspect the window already have a child.

Comment: Did the exception *really* not contain a message?  If it did, could you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the Grid part from your **XAML**

If your code looks like this

```
<Window x:Class="NameSpace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Grid></Grid>
</Window>
```

It Should Look like

```
<Window x:Class="NameSpace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">

</Window>
```

Comment: You can upvote and Accept it as answer as it resolved your problem